# MySql Inner join where data not available there but want to give condition on it

Tags: mysql

This is my tabel, relation with dependent

> Table: **data**

```
+---------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
| nama    | id_propinsi  | id_kabupaten  | id_kecamatan |
+---------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
| A       | 12           | 11            | 01           |
+---------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
| B       | 13           | 01            | 01           |
+---------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
| C       | 12           | 11            | 00           |
+---------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
```

> Table: **propinsi**

```
+--------------+---------------+
| id_propinsi  | nama_propinsi |
+--------------+---------------+
| 12           | jawa barat    |
+--------------+---------------+
| 13           | jawa timur    |
+--------------+---------------+
```

> Table: **kabupaten**

```
+--------------+---------------+---------------+
| id_propinsi  | id_kabupaten  | nama_kabupaten|
+--------------+---------------+---------------+
| 12           | 11            | depok         |
+--------------+---------------+---------------+
| 13           | 01            | magelang      |
+--------------+---------------+---------------+
```

> Table: **kecamatan**

```
+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+
| id_propinsi  | id_kabupaten  | id_kecamatan | nama_kecamatan|
+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+
| 12           | 11            | 01           | sawangan      |
+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+
| 13           | 01            | 01           | pasuruan      |
+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+
```

**OUTPUT NOW (FALSE)**

```
A | Jawa barat | Depok | Sawangan 
B | Jawa Timur | Magelang | Pasuruan
```

**I want to OUTPUT THIS (RIGHT)**

```
A | Jawa barat | Depok | Sawangan 
B | Jawa Timur | Magelang | Pasuruan
C | Jawa barat | Depok | -
```

I try to many querys but still cant get the right condition, with CASE, INNER JOIN OR .. 
**because id_kecamatan=00 unavailable on table kecamatan**
may you know how to do it to output like that i want .. ???
Thank you so much

my query is

```
SELECT name, nama_propinsi, nama_kabupaten, nama_kecamatan FROM data D
INNER JOIN propinsi P ON D.id_propinsi=P.id_propinsi
INNER JOIN kabupaten K ON D.id_propinsi=P.id_propinsi AND D.id_kabupaten=K.id_kabupaten
INNER JOIN kecamatan C ON D.id_propinsi=P.id_propinsi AND D.id_kabupaten=K.id_kabupaten AND D.id_kecamatan=C.id_kecamatan
```

Comment: You need to use `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Left join ?not using case ? or if ? @1000111

Comment: oh god .. you right ... thank you i was try it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace all your `INNER JOIN`s by `LEFT JOIN`.

And with the help of `COALESCE` function you can treat the `NULL` value as hyphen (`-`).

```
SELECT
    NAME,
    COALESCE(nama_propinsi,'-') AS prop,
    COALESCE(nama_kabupaten,'-') AS kabu,
    COALESCE(nama_kecamatan,'-') AS keca
FROM
    data D
LEFT JOIN propinsi P ON D.id_propinsi = P.id_propinsi
LEFT JOIN kabupaten K ON D.id_kabupaten = K.id_kabupaten
LEFT JOIN kecamatan C ON D.id_kecamatan = C.id_kecamatan
```

Comment: why you using all left join ?

Comment: okey thats right .. wait a minute to ceklis (verified your answer)

Comment: Used all left joins because any of the last three tables might not contain the corresponding data.

Comment: By the way, your last two joins contain redundant join conditions. I've removed them.

Comment: ohh okeey .. so the structure field on table its important yes? .. if the structure table kecamatan create this [id_kecamatan | id_propinsi | id_kabupaten | nama_kecamatan] can't using left join ?

Comment: Still the query would be same as long as the `data` table contains all those `foreign keys`.